# Combinations conceptual confusion

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we toss a fair coin 43 times. What is the number of cases where number of  heads > number of tails?

I'm doing this like this: we'll have a satisfactory case only when number of heads are 22, 23, 24 ....... 43.

Number of ways in which we can have 22 heads in $\binom{43}{22}$, number of ways we get 23 heads is $\binom {43} {24}$ etc.

Total number of ways is a combination of them, i.e $$\binom{43} {22} + \binom{43} {23} + .... \binom{43} {43}$$ which is equal to $2^n$ i.e $2^{22}$? The answer however is $2^{42}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What should $n$ be in your formula "$2^n$"?  Incidentally, since there is an odd number of tosses, each case where heads exceed tails corresponds one-to-one with a case where tails exceed heads (just reverse the counts), whence the answer must be exactly one-half the total number of possible outcomes, giving $2^{43}/2 = 2^{42}$ as claimed.

Comment: Ohh, well that makes sense. n was supposed to be the number of terms. I studied that the summation of combinations $\binom {n} {0} +.... \binom {n} {n}$ is $2^n$. I thought The sum $\binom {43} {22}$+ ...+ $\binom {43} {43}$ would be equal to $\binom {43} {0}$ + .... + $\binom {43} {21}$. Hence n = 22

Comment: Replace $43$ by $3$ and $22$ by $2$ so you can see what goes wrong in this simpler case where the binomial coefficients are small ($1,3,3,1$).

Comment: A very useful combinatorial identity is $\dbinom{n}{k} = \dbinom{n}{n-k}$. Try applying this to each and every term in $\dbinom {43} {22}+\cdots+\dbinom{43}{43}$. Then ponder the fact that if $x=y$ and $x+y = 2^{43}$ then it must be that $x=y=2^{42}$.